# How to set the Only Oscilloscope line to horizontal axis in aurio Touch example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The verticle Green Line of the Oscilloscope is needed to be set on x axis in [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) Example... To some extent i am able to manage the screen except the Green line. But now  wanted to set line to horizontal axis... Do i have to only modify `-(void)drawOscilloscpe` method?? or some more complexity is waiting for me???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `-(void)drawOscilloscope` method instead of glRotatef(-90.0,0.,0.,1.) i have made it

```
glRotatef(-180.,0.,0.,1.)
```

Also after doing this we have to save the state of the graph so we need to push into matrix. like below.

```
glPushMatrix();
```